# ItemsRepeater throws System.InvalidCastException when using converter

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

**Describe the bug**

I'm designing an app like NetFlix home page. For a better user experience, I used some converters in ItemsRepeater data template.
Then the app crashes every time staring, and throw exceoption `System.InvalidCastException`.
But if I don't use converter, the app starts and runs well.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

```
1. Go to MovieTemplate, change Image's source to
Source="{x:Bind PosterUrl, Converter={StaticResource imageUrlCompress}}"
2. Run app.
```

**Expected behavior**

App runs well and show the normal home page.

Win: 18362.418
Microsoft.UI.Xaml: 2.2.190917002

**Additional context**

Here is a small [repo](https://github.com/hupo376787/ItemsRepeater-throws-System.InvalidCastException-when-using-converter), and special thanks to @XamlBrewer's repo.

In WINUI 3.0 alpha, All converters causes crash, including TextBlock converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and triggered this error.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'.

The error states that the string cannot be directly assigned to `Image.Source`.

You can rewrite Converter like this:

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("https://www.viu.com/ott/hk/v1/imgprocess/reduceImage.php?p=50&img=" + value.ToString())
        );
}
```

`Image.Source` accepts data based on `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource` as the source of the image, and `BitmapImage` is one of them.

Directly using the binding can use the string as the source, because XAML has an internal Converter, but when you explicitly set the Converter, the internal Converter will no longer work, you have to convert the output yourself.

---

In addition, WinUI 3.0 is currently in the preview stage. If you encounter problems, please ask an issue at [WinUI's Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) repository.

Best regards.

Comment: OK, I'll try. Thanks. I have already submit this issue to github, but no reply yet.

Comment: And another question, I didn't find any error message you wrote, I only got `System.InvalidCastException`. Can you tell me how to find `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'.`

Comment: When the error occurs, you will jump to the `App.g.i.cs` page. Notice the "Local Variables" window at the bottom left of the Visual Studio. There is a detailed error message and stack trace in the variable `e` (which is Exception).

Comment: Yeah, I found it. Thx.